# Edit file on server with PHP and C#

Tags: c#, php, text-files, server

Here is my C# code:

```cs
WebClient myClient = new WebClient();
NameValueCollection inputs = new NameValueCollection();
inputs.Add("decrement", "true");
System.Uri uri = new System.Uri ("http://myserver/myPHP.php");
myClient.UploadValuesAsync (uri, "POST", inputs);
```

Here is my `myPHP.php` file on the server:

```php
if($_POST['decrement'] == "true") {
    $file = './myTextFile.txt';
    // Open the file to get existing content
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    // Append a new person to the file
    $current .= "John Smith\n";
    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
}
```

The txt file is not being written to, why not?

NOTE: `myPHP.php` and `myTextFile.txt` are in the same directory on the server

Comment: Probably because $_POST['decrement'] does not == "true"

Comment: But I set it in the key value pair from the C#. Please level with me, I have no php experience.

Comment: Or because using `./` for file paths doesn't work. You need to use a function that gives you the path of the server's htdocs.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is directly under htdocs:

```
 $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/myTextFile.txt';
```

Comment: What if it is not directly under httpdocs. It's under a folder on the same level.

Comment: @Ogen, then something like `$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/folder/myTextFile.txt';`

Comment: @Ogen, Basically the point is, doing `./folder/` won't work.  You need the full path, like `c:/whatever/whatever`. Using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` just gives you the `c:/prog files/apache/htdocs` or wherever you installed it.